# Check if 2d shape composed of block has been cut

Tags: arrays, 2d, shapes, divide

I know that the title of this topic might be confusing, but I didn't know how to explain it in a single sentence!
I'll try to be more clear, I have a 2d array of boolean values, every value states if that particular position (or block) is alive or not.

Let's make an example:

1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1

This array contains 16 "alive" blocks, now I can "kill" some blocks, changing their state from 1 to 0.
What I would like to do is to know if after a "kill", the group splits in two or more separate groups, for example:

1 1 0 1
1 1 0 1
0 1 0 1
1 1 1 1

This shape is still "intact", since the group of 0 is not cutting any of the 1 groups, but in this case:

1 1 0 1
1 1 0 1
0 0 0 1
1 1 1 1

Now I've killed the only bit who was keeping all the 1 together, the shape has been divided in two smaller groups!
I've tried checking the neighbours of the last killed bit but then I can't be sure of other possible connection of the shape.
I've also tried a pathfinding algorithm but this operation should be very fast and a pathfinding is too complex.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick any of the alive blocks and do a flood-fill and then check if it got to all the other live blocks.

Comment: Isn't this too heavy?
I mean, my array could be 128*128, checking if every block reaches every other block is a lot of instructions!
And I'm not sure this can help me identify the divided groups :(

Comment: @user1716905  You only do one flood fill.  The seed point for the fill is arbitrary, it can be any of the alive blocks.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill

Comment: It worked, I didn't think of flooding in all the direction, I only tried vertically and horizontally, thanks a lot, it works like a charm :)